# encotrar elementos de un array dentro de otro array

Tags: javascript, algoritmos

Como podría hacer para buscar elementos de un array que están en otra array?. Los array podrían ser de diferente longitud.

Ejemplo, tengo un array: `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

y tengo otro array `[2,4,5]`

Entonces quiero recorrer el primer array y si encuentra los elementos del segundo array haga algo.

Comment: Creo el método `includes()` te puede ayudar

Comment: si, podria utilizalo si busco un valor dentro del array pero nose si se puede en el caso planteado

Comment: Si encuentra todos? alguno? quierés que haga algo por cada uno que encuentre?

Comment: no, no se encentran todos, como en el ejemplo pueden encontrarse solo 3 elementos. Si por cada uno que encuentre tiene que hacer algo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Básicamente lo que hay que hacer es por cada elemento del primer array miro si existe en el segundo array.

con JS puro:

```js
const array1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
const array2 = [2,4,5];
let existe = false;
for (const valorABuscar of array1) {
  if (existe) break;
  existe = array2.includes(valorABuscar);
}

console.log('Existe: ', existe);
```

Como lo haría ahora:

```js
const array1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
const array2 = [2,4,5];
const existe = array1.some(valorABuscar => array2.includes(valorABuscar));

console.log('Existe: ', existe);
```

**EDICIÓN DESPUÉS DE SU PRIMER COMENTARIO**

Haz el for a partir del segundo array y cuando encuentre el numero en el primero llamas a la función:

```js
const array1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
const array2 = [2,11,4,5];
for (const valorABuscar of array2) {
  const existe = array1.includes(valorABuscar);
  if (!existe) continue;
  console.log('Llamar a la función: ', valorABuscar);
  //funcion();
}
```

Comment: claro pero yo necesino ejecutar una funcion si se encuentra el elemento. Cada vez que se encuentre el elemento del segundo array en el primer array ejecutar una funcion.

Comment: He editado mi respuesta a ver si te sirve

Comment: muchas Gracias !

Comment: @GuillermoBaban, por favor, si la respuesta te ha servido como se presupone por tus gracias, dale al check de la misma para mostrarla como respondida, y de paso, dale un punto a JordiBaliellasPortet por la buena respuesta y que aumente su reputación en la comunidad. Un saludo

Comment: Por cierto, habría que acostumbrarse a no contestar preguntas que no muestran un trabajo previo o al menos sus intentos por lograrlo. Recuerda que la comunidad no está para realizarle las tareas a nadie, simplemente para resolver dudas o solucionar problemas. Un saludo